# Can not create kubernetes secret using go client

Tags: go, kubernetes

I am trying to create a secret using this function

```
func (ks *KubeSession) DeploySecret(secretName string, secretType string, secretMap map[string][]byte) error {
    InfoLogger.Printf("deploying secret %s", secretName)
    secret := corev1.Secret{
        TypeMeta: metav1.TypeMeta{
            Kind:       "Secret",
            APIVersion: "v1",
        },
        ObjectMeta: metav1.ObjectMeta{
            Name: secretName,
        },
        Data: secretMap,
        Type: secretType,
    }

    _, err := ks.ClientSet.CoreV1().Secrets(JOB_NAMESPACE).Create(context.TODO(), &secret, metav1.CreateOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

It is getting the following error:

```
cannot use secretType (variable of type string) as "k8s.io/api/core/v1".SecretType value in struct literal
```

Though, it works fine when I use a hardcoded string instead, like that:

```
...
Type: "generic"
...
```

How can I substitute this variable, so that I do not have to use hardcoded values instead?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.

Found the right way to declare the composite type:

```
Type: corev1.SecretType(secretType)
```